# Remove line from big txtfile in Java

Tags: java, text, io, line

Does anybody know how to remove a line from a textfile.

I'm looking for something else than read and write line by line and skip the line you want te remove.

For example: My file counts 1346 lines and I want to remove line 520.

Comment: do you by any chance know the contents of the last line?

Comment: Do you know the position of the line ? Or do you know what does the line look like ?

Comment: I can make my program that I compute the position of the line, yeah.

Comment: I was looking at RandomAccessFile to merge 2 of them, but I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934458/how-to-delete-a-particular-line-from-random-access-file , so I don't know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A text file isn't something that supports zero-cost reorganization.  It is simply a contiguous sequence of bytes.  If you want to remove some bytes from the middle of the file (and by implication move all the following bytes up cover the removed bytes), you have to copy and re-write all those following bytes.

You have a few options.  Read the entire file into memory, do your removal, and then write the file out.  (hopefully to a temp file which you rename over on top of the original after successfully completing the write)  Or do some fancy footwork with just reading in a buffers worth of data from the source file and doing some work on it.

Comment: I was going to do the same comment: whatever the language, there is no magic to remove bytes in the middle of a file (in most OSes I know, at least). So I just +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does the solution need to be written in Java? The UNIX commands **sed** and **grep** are made for just this purpose and will likely perform better. If you are running Windows, you can get access to these tools via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or there might be native ports out there.

Comment: I agree, but I suspect that this question should have had a "homework" tag on it, hence it has to stay in java.  (notice the letter 'O' in the number 52O, instead of 520.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Rob is right.
try this

```
sed -e '520d' <yourfile>
```

redirect the output to new file

here 520 is the line number you want to delete

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire file in, do a regex replace (given that you know the exact match etc) then write the file back out.

Personally I'm not sure of how much value this answer is :)

Comment: that is like the way I explained. I don't want to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you know the length (or the content of the last line):

```
long lastLineLength = lastLine.length();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("RandFile.txt", "rw");
long length = raf.length();
raf.setLength(length - lastLineLength );
raf.close();
```

Comment: this is more what I want but, it is just the last line

Comment: sorry, can't quite understand your comment

Comment: @stefita you remove only the last line. This is not the question, I guess he wants to remove an arbitrary line.

Comment: yes, the author changed the description. The first draft was about the last line.